# use lines as arguments in one call (xargs-like)

Tags: bash, arguments

I have one function that prints several lines which I want to use as arguments to another function:

```
lsx() {
    echo 1 is one
    echo 2 are two
}

somefun() {
    for arg in "$@"; do
        echo "arg='$arg'"
    done
}
```

How can I "elegantly" call `somefun()` with lines from `lsx()` as arguments?

<strike>What I do now is loop through lines using `while`, storing lines in array, but this seems ugly and way too work.</strike> (Edit: This does not work due to while+subshell).   I think there should be simple (even portable?) way but can't come up with one.

(If `somefun` was an external command then I'd just use *xargs* but it's not.)

Answer (score 4):

#### Without xargs

```
$ ( IFS=$'\n'; somefun $(lsx) )
arg='1 is one'
arg='2 are two'
```

The subshell is used so that the change to `IFS` is local, not global.

**Limitation**: This subjects the output of `lsx` to pathname expansion which may or may not be a problem.

#### With xargs

To access a shell function with xargs, we need to run a shell.  To have access to `somefun` in a child shell, we need first to export it.  Thus:

```
$ export -f somefun
$ lsx | xargs -d'\n' bash -c 'somefun "$@"' SomeFun
arg='1 is one'
arg='2 are two'
```

The first argument to `bash` is assigned to `$0` and serves as the program name in error messages.  This can be an arbitrary word.  Here, we use `SomeFun`.

#### Examples of the pathname expansion issues

```
$ lsx() { echo '1 is one*'; echo '2 are two*'; }
$ touch '1 is one'{1..3} two{a..c}
$ ( IFS=$'\n'; somefun $(lsx) )
arg='1 is one1'
arg='1 is one2'
arg='1 is one3'
arg='2 are two*'
```

As you can see the first line of output was expanded into three lines.

The shell first performs *word-splitting* on the output of `$(lsx)`.  Because IFS is set to a newline character, the output is split into lines.  The shell then performs *pathname expansion*.  Because there are files that match the glob `1 is one*`, this glob is expanded into a list of those names.  In our example, there are no files that match the glob `2 is two*` and, so, that glob is not expanded.  (Under the default IFS, `2 is two*` would have been split into three words and the third would have matched the files `twoa`, `twob`, and `twoc`.)

The `xargs` approach avoids pathname expansion:

```
$ export -f somefun
$ lsx | xargs -d'\n' bash -c 'somefun "$@"' SomeFun
arg='1 is one*'
arg='2 are two*'
```

Comment: Nice. Just a note that the pathname expansion applies to *whole* `lsx` output; not just each line. (I'm sure you know it but took a while to get to *me*.)

Comment: @AloisMahdal I just added a section to illustrate the pathname expansion issues and show that the `xargs` approach avoids them.

Answer (score 2):

Trivial solution:

```
IFS="
"
somefun $(lsx)
```

Comment: This makes each word an argument, not each line.

Comment: updated... IFS is also trivial

Comment: It's not trivial, it's the key to the solution, and the feature that the OP probably wasn't even aware of.

Comment: You might prefer to write that as `IFS=$'\n'` if the literal newline offends or is hard to parse.